# How to reuse objects, but with different parameters?

Tags: c++

I have made a Wiegand Calculator with a server and a web interface on an ESP32.

**My issue** is that every time I input another decimal I have to create another object and I am not sure this is safe with the limited amount of memory on the ESP32 and also I don't think that creating objects forever is the best practice.

I have a class with a constructor that gets a decimal number and transforms it into a Wiegand 26-bit binary number:

```
class Wiegand {
  private:
    std::vector<bool> wiegandArray = std::vector<bool>(26, false);
    uint8_t facilityCode;
    uint16_t cardNumber;
    void calculate(uint32_t dec) {
      // transform dec number into binary number using single bit shift operation
      // and store it in wiegandArray[]
      for (int i = 24; i > 0; --i) {
        wiegandArray[i] = dec & 1;
        dec >>= 1;
      }
      // check for parity of the first 12 bits
      bool even = 0;
      for(int i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
        even ^= wiegandArray[i];
      }
      // add 0 or 1 as first bit (leading parity bit - even) based on the number of 'ones' in the first 12 bits
      wiegandArray[0] = even;

      // check for parity of the last 12 bits
      bool odd = 1;
      for(int i = 13; i < 25; i++) {
        odd ^= wiegandArray[i];
      }
      // add 0 or 1 as last bit (trailing parity bit - odd) based on the number of 'ones' in the last 12 bits
      wiegandArray[25] = odd;
    }
  public:
    Wiegand(uint32_t id) {
      calculate(id);
      facilityCode = id >> 16;
      cardNumber = id & 0xffff;
    }
    //returns a 26 length std::vector<bool>
    std::vector<bool> getWiegandBinary() {
      return wiegandArray;
    }
};
```

and I call that constructor every time I get a new decimal number:

```
std::vector<bool> _array;

void setup() {
//server initialization
//check for web parameters
if(p->name() == "getWiegand") {
            String wiegandID = p->value();
            Wiegand card(wiegandID.toInt());
            _array = card.getWiegandBinary();
            change = true;
          }
}
void loop() {
  if(change) {
    change = false;
    for(int i = 0; i<26; i++) {
      Serial.print(_array[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Also, doing this transformation using a class actually makes things harder on an ESP.
I need to make a new object every time I get a new value inside `void setup()` and that object won't be defined in `void loop()`, so I have to use globally declared variables, such as `_array = card.getWiegandBinary();`, to be able to access the `getters` from the class.

Should I drop classed and do it with globally declared functions and variables ?

Comment: Any particular reason why you use `std::vector<bool>` instead of [`std::bitset<26>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset)? It'll most likely use less memory.

Comment: In any case, you would need to show the interaction between `setup` and `loop` before anyone can tell you how to best structure your code. Are these running in different threads? Or are there signal handlers involved? Where is `change` defined? Where does `p` come from and what is it? Please provide a [mcve]...